# Accessing a triple pointer inside a function with array notation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say I have a double pointer to a structure in main (i.e. an array of pointers to a struct) and I want to pass it to a function, where it will be filled. Let's say I would like to pass every "output" to the function with a "&" in front, so that it's clear which parameters are outputs. This would mean that in the function I have to deal with a triple pointer.

```
void fillarray(int elements, struct MyStruct *** array, int * output) {
    // fill the array
        // (see below)
    // return output
    *output = ...
}

int main() {
    // some code
    // ...

    int elements_count = 10;
    int some_int_output;

    struct MyStruct ** = malloc(elements_count * sizeof(struct MyStruct *));
    for (i = 0; i < elements_count; i++) {
        array_of_pointers[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct MyStruct));

    fillarray(elements_count, &array_of_pointers, &some_int_output);

    // some code
    // ...
    }
```

Now I would like to access (and fill) the array inside the function using an array notation:

```
for (i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    *array[i] = ... // ONLY WORKS FOR i=0 THEN SEGFAULT
}
```

in analogy to how I return an integer output (`*output = ...`).

Instead I found that the only (?) way to access it would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    *(*array + i) = ... // WORKS FOR ALL ELEMENTS
}
```

I think the problem has to do with which "pointer dimension" gets dereferenced first, so that `*array[i]` does not access the intended memory while `*(*array + i)` does. Using this second notation would make things more complicated and error-prone, offsetting the (supposed) advantage of having the "&" in the function call.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to better re-write this, in order to use an array notation inside the function, while keeping the triple pointer? Is there a way to influence the "pointer dimension order"?

Thanks in advance.

PS I am aware there are (many) other ways of achieving the same result and I have successfully used a few of them. Here I was interested in knowing if the above conditions could be satisfied, while learning more about pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it has to do with operator precedence, this

```
*array[i]
```

is not equivalent to

```
(*array)[i]
```

but instead to

```
*(array[i]) => *(*(array + i))
```

because the array subscript operator has higher precedence than the indirection operator, so adding parentheses makes the first expression work.

Notice that for `i == 0` this

```
*(array[i]) => *(*(array + i))
```

means

```
*(array[0]) => *(*(array + 0)) => *(*array) == *(*array + 0)
```

so there is no real difference which operator is evaluated first, but as `i > 0` there will be a difference.

Comment: OK, the notation `(*array)[i]` works indeed. I would say it is an acceptable trade-off. One would only have to remember to add parentheses when dealing with ***.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be:

```
struct MyStruct **arr = *array;
```

Now you can use `arr` like a normal double pointer.

Comment: Also an interesting solution, probably worth it if we do a lot of computations inside the function.

Comment: @m2oTech this solution is actually more elegant, I just didn't mention it because I was trying to explain why your code failed. But I would choos this solution, it makes it clearer,

Comment: @iharob, I think your solution more directly addresses the problem (which is indeed only a formal problem). I also find this solution elegant and I'd probably also prefer it, again less error-prone.